# Why mic is not working of Amazon's Fire tablet in React Native?

Tags: react-native, tablet, microphone, voice

I'm getting this error while initiating the voice module from this package @react-native-community/voice

errorstarting voice [error: not allowed to bind to service intent { act=android.speech.recognitionservice cmp=amazon.speech.sim/com.amazon.alexa.multimodal.assistant.alexavoiceinteractionservice }]

I tried to initiate the voice module but it is not getting initiated.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you can check:

- Have you included the RECORD_AUDIO permission?
- Have you got Alexa enabled on the device?
- Is the "Microphone" permission enabled for your app?

Comment: Yes I've got Alexa in that. Permissions are given properly.

Comment: Do I need to include any other package to enable microphone in Amazon's Fire Tablet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).